OpenCV + RSTP + GStreamer - VIGI IP Camera (C330I) re-connection too late
I use openCV and
VideoCapture('rtspsrc location=rtsp://admin:qwer1234@172.16.20.72/stream1 latency=0 ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,format=BGR ! appsink drop=1')

I use HIK VISION IP Camera and VIGI IP Camera
When Python Code exited, that code is restarted.
At that time HIK Vision Camera VideoCapture works well, but VIGI Camera VideoCapture does not works.
It takes long time to re-connection. But rtsp protocol works well
Does anyone knows why it takes too long to re-connect VideoCapture with RTSP?
I don't know how to deal with this problem

Is the stream from the camera continuously running or you restart it every time before running the example fist time?

Hi, @Akkshay. Camera is always running, although python code is over or restarts.
When I set stream rtsp with VLC Player when opencv does not connect rstp, VLC shows the camera stream very well

Do you mean,  the opencv stream takes longer to connect when VLC is accessing the stream? what happens if VLC is not running? Also, I suggest running your example with GST_DEBUG level 3 or 4 to get detailed logs.
GST_DEBUG=3 python3 example.py

I read logs, gstreamer keep trying to get resource from rtsp, but " Could not read from resource" Error occured.
A few minutes later, gstreamer can get resource from rtsp and openCV can show frames

I guess the problem that can not read from resource is up to Camera. Becuz When I use another Network Camera with rtsp, that  camera's reconnection is very fast

In that case, VLC should have problem reconnecting as well but it reconnects fine with VLC right?

Yes, I can stream camera with vlc network streaming very well.
But In python, GST_DEBUG shows me "could not read from resource" Error and VideoCapture can not get frames from rtsp.

I want to know why gstreamer rtsp streaming with openCV not well.
